# Fixing distortions for Baden-Württemberg

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system

I'm working in an area in Baden-Württemberg, Germany. I loaded some OSM data in QGIS but the map display is distorted.

I tried ftools define projection with many different projections but nothing changed.

I tried: - WGS 84/ World Mercator - DHDN / Gauss-Kruger zone 2 - Google mercator - ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N - DHDN / Gauss-Krugerzone 3 - DHDN / Soldner Berlin

and many others...but nothing worked. There was no difference visible.

Answer (score 1):

The basic thing you are stumbling upon is the difference between **layer** CRS and **project** CRS.

The OpenStreetMap data is in lat/long degrees, so that layer should have the CRS EPSG:4326. You can set it with right-click on the layer `-> Set CRS for layer`.

The project CRS can be different, and should be in your case. You can change tthat with `Settings -> Project Settings`.

EPSG:3857 should be the projection you are used to when looking at the OpenStreetMap Website.

And `On-the-fly-projection` should be activated.